# Nodemon doesn't exec command while restarting

Tags: node.js, npm, exec, restart, nodemon

I have a problem about the --exec parameter of nodemon. Following this article (http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) i try to set up my dev environnement with only NPM but nodemon refuse to serve my node server when i put --exec argument.

My scripts in package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf src/app/build/app.bundle.js",
    "build": "browserify src/app/scripts/app.js > src/app/build/app.bundle.js",
    "serve": "nodemon server.js --ignore src/app/build --exec \"npm run build\"",
    "cbs": "npm run clean && npm run build && npm run open && npm run serve",

    "open:dev": "opener http://localhost:9000",
},
```

And this is what i get in my git bash :

```
poc-js-pdf@0.0.1 serve C:\Users\Mdeumie\Projets\Archi\poc-js-pdf
nodemon server.js --ignore src/app/build --exec "npm run build"

[nodemon] 1.8.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `npm run build server.js`

poc-js-pdf@0.0.1 build C:\Users\Mdeumie\Projets\Archi\poc-js-pdf
browserify src/app/scripts/app.js > src/app/build/app.bundle.js "server.js"

[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Off course my server.js is not reachable in my browser and i don't understand why it seems to be executing this ***starting npm run build server.js***

Thanks if someone has an idea about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing the `--exec *` from your serve script and change it to

```
"npm run build && nodemon"
```

Make a file `nodemon.json` in your root and inside try putting

```
{
  "ignore": ["src/app/build"],
  "events": {
    "exit": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

So your nodemon will run and do its thing and then it should trigger the build on restart

List of events: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/events.md

Comment: Thanks ! It's working, i just did a little change : i choose event "exit" to be sure that the npm run build is executed before restarting the server.